# How to get a value in a tagged union data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, if I create a dataype like this:

```
data MyT = MyT Int deriving (Show)
myValue = MyT 42
```

I can get the Int value passing 'myValue' to a function and doing pattern matching:

```
getInt :: MyT -> Int                                                  
getInt (MyT n) = n
```

It seems to me that something simpler should be possible. Is there another way?

Also, I tried a lambda function:

```
(\(MyT n) -> n) myValue
```

It doesn't work and I don't understand why not.
I get the error:

> ```
> The function `\ (MyT n) -> n' is applied to two arguments,
>     but its type `MyT -> Int' has only one
> ```

**EDIT:** 
Of course, sepp2k below, is right about my lambda function working OK. I was doing:

```
(\(MyT n) -> n) myT 42
```

instead of

```
(\(MyT n) -> n) (myT 42)
```

Comment: You can bundle the constructor and the accessor together using record syntax, like this: `data MyT = MyT { getInt :: Int } deriving (Show)`.

Comment: I had a difficult time deciding the accepted answer. All are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the record syntax

```
data MyT = MyT {unMyT :: Int} deriving (Show)
```

which gives you the projection for free

```
unMyT :: MyT -> Int
```

This is nice if your data type has only one constructor (including `newtype`s). For data types involving more than one constrctor, projection functions tend to be unsafe (e.g., `head`,`tail`), and pattern matching is usually preferred instead. GHC checks for non-exhaustive patterns if you enable warnings, and can help to spot errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get at the value of MyT inside a larger function without defining a helper function, you could either use `case of` or pattern matching in local variable definitions. Here are examples of that (assuming that `g` produces a `MyT` and `f` takes an `Int`):

Using `case`:

```
myLargerFunction x = f (case g x of MyT n => n)
```

Or with local variables:

```
myLargerFunction x = f myInt
  where MyT myInt = g x
```

Or using `let` instead of `where`:

```
myLargerFunction x =
  let MyT myInt = g x in
  f myInt
```

Your lambda function should (and in fact does) also work fine. Your error message suggests that in your real code you're really doing something like `(\(MyT n) -> n) myValue somethingElse` (presumably by accident).

Answer (score 2):

NewTypes create a distinct type and do not have an extra level of indirection like algebraic datatypes. See the Haskell report for more information:

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.2.3

```
Prelude> newtype Age = Age { unAge :: Int } deriving (Show)
Prelude> let personAge = Age 42
Prelude> personAge
Age {unAge = 42}
Prelude> (unAge personAge) + 1
43
```

Using a lambda function:

```
Prelude> (\(Age age) -> age * 2) personAge
84
```